# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am currently following a video tutorial to make this notepad app for school and I can't figure out what is wrong. It is saying

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

This dependency was already there. I am running the latest version of android studio Arctic Fox.

Picture of the error I got...
[image: Picture of the error I got...]

Comment: It's a problem with your build.gradle(Module:app), please post its code.